# As limit $x\to 5$, $\frac 1x \to \frac 15$. If $\epsilon = 0.05$ what is $\delta $ equal to?

Tags: calculus, epsilon-delta

As limit $x\to 5$, $\frac 1x \to \frac 15$. If $\epsilon = 0.05$ what is $\delta $ equal to?

The answer is $\delta=\frac 1{505}$. Does anyone know how to get this? I have been banging my head for an hour :P.

Comment: $\delta$ is never unique, if $\delta$ works any positive number less than $\delta$ works.

Answer (score 1):

We know that

> $$\left|{1\over x}-{1\over 5}\right|<{1\over 20}\iff \left|{x-5\over 5x}\right|\le {1\over 20}$$

Since $|x-5|<\delta$ we have that $|5x|\ge 5(5-\delta)$ hence we have

$$\left|{1\over x}-{1\over 5}\right|\le {\delta\over 5(5-\delta)}$$

and we want the RHS to be bounded by ${1\over 20}$ hence we get

$$20\delta < 5(5-\delta)\iff 25\delta <25\iff \delta <1.$$

Not sure how they got $505^{-1}$, certainly that also works since ${1\over 505}<1$, but then--as usual--choices of $\delta$ aren't unique.